# setPixmap() function wont show image in a linux system - pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

```
        image = QPixmap("dog.jpeg")
        self.photo.setPixmap(image)
```

the set pixmap function just wont work, it works in windows though

tried to set the pixmap of the label photo.
the pixmap image is not displayed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use an absolute path.